# Creating Directory in the Memory

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

How can we create a directory in the Memory as a stream and then using the System.IO package for the zip the package directory.

Additional Info : I need to do it memory because i will be using it in the Windows Azure .So i am not sure i will have permission in the Server for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Doing all this in memory might not be such a good idea, especially when you're running in Windows Azure. Know that your instances have a limited amount of memory available and you should keep the load on your instances to a minimum.

Why not use a [local resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx) instead? This is a part on the disk where you can use for whatever you need (in your case create a directory, maybe add some files and zip it):

```
LocalResource resource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MySampleStorage");
Directory.CreateDirectory(resource.RootPath + "\\NewFolder");
File.Create(resource.RootPath + "\\NewFolder\\NewFile.txt");
```

Note that this data won't be persisted (you could loose it at any time). Once you are done with whatever you need to do you should take the file  and save it as a blob (See: [How to Use the Blob Storage Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/))